# How to convert column values to lower case and get data?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I have user nickname in my table in case insensitive type.

I tried to get a record from the table using this query but did not succeed:

```
$user = User::whereIn('LCASE(nickname)', strtolower($nickname));
```

**Error message:**

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

How I can get users by nickname in case insensitive type?

Comment: You missed `->first()`, so your code would be `$user = User::whereIn('LCASE(nickname)', strtolower($nickname))->first();`. Or if you want to get a Collection you use `->get()` instead of `->first()`

Comment: I tired `->first()` and `->get()` but error not changed. @DestinatioN

Comment: Have you tried ```$user = User::whereIn('LCASE(nickname)', [strtolower($nickname)]);```? whereIn expects an arrayable parameter. I'd suggest to change it to a normal where instead.

Comment: Sry i missed, that you use `whereIn` instead of `where` like @AdrianHernandez-Lopez answered

Comment: When I try your code and `->first()` return error message: `Unknown column 'LCASE(nickname)' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `LCASE(nickname)` in (otabek) limit 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WhereIn` expects an array of values, in this case I'd suggest t change it to a base where (and add a `first` so you get the first value or use a `get` to return all users that matches).

```
$user = User::where('nickname', 'like', '%' . strtolower($nickname) . '%')->first();
```

Comment: **Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'LCASE(nickname)' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `LCASE(nickname)` = andreas limit 1)**

Comment: I have updated the answer to replace LCASE with the like operator

Comment: Updated work now for me, thanks @ Adrian Hernandez-Lopez